# Newbie: should I learn c#, VB.Net or VBA/VB for excel programming?

Tags: c#, vb.net, vba

My background: Mostly C programming. I have some (very recently...last 2 months) acquired JAVA (novice) skills. All my limited experience is based on developing for linux.

I would like to do some excel programming for work purposes. My main interest is in starting to create "dashboards" and charts/reporting from excel sheets as I'm sick and tired of  updating many sheets by hand. I'm lazy so I love to automate wherever I can :-)

Which one of these "new" languages (for me) would you recommend to learn? I'm also hoping that if/when I'm getting more familiar with Windows/MS Office environment I can do more "powerfull" things.

Comment: Thanks a lot for all the feedback guys! I think the desicion maker was Thorarin....VBA might not be around for that much longer and if it is being replaced with .net then maybe C# is the way to go as I might be able to do even more with it in the future.

Again...thanks for all the great feedback, very useful!

Answer (score 9):

If your main goal is to optimise your Excel tasks, then VBA is the language to learn.

The good thing is that if you have any programming background the learning curve is extremely straightforward.

Just run "Record Macro", perform a task, then look at the code that was generated. You've got a working example to learn from.

Comment: Thanks Andrew. My main "concern" is that I immediately look at things like creating structures/classes to solve some of my problems, and that then brings me to vb.net and c#. I have a beginners book in VBA but there is no reference to doing anything like that, except for using arrays. Does this require a mindset change from myside or?

Comment: @nomad.alien: I don't think so. Even if you start with C mindset, you can get your things done. Maybe your code will look funny, but it's not a reason to be feel ashamed.

Answer (score 5):

I personally prefer C# as a language, but in terms of *released* versions, VB.NET is a better language to use for Office interop. C# 4 has improved this situation a *lot* though, with named arguments and optional parameters, ref argument faking and COM PIA linking.

If you can use C# 4, that might be the best option for you - but if you're stuck with fully released versions, you might want to go for VB.NET instead.

Comment: Hi Jon. Not sure what you mean with "fully released versions". My requirements are to use this only for myself, so it's not somethingthat's going to be supported through the company or by anyone else. Mostly to scratch my own itch.

Comment: I mean "versions which aren't in beta" :) If you're happy using the beta 1 of Visual Studio 2010 (which is a bit slow, but certainly usable) then you might want to go straight to C#.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to dig straight into excel automation, I'd stick to VBA. If you're more interested in extending your knowledge, I'd choose one of the .NET languages, probably VB.NET.

C# seems to be more prestigious/popular, but it's also closer to what you already know. If you learn the .NET Framework using VB, that and your C/java syntax means you'll be able to read C#. It would also give a smoother transition to VBA if you change your mind.

Answer (score 1):

Since you know Java & C, C# should be the easiest to learn.  More jobs for C# skills too, if that's important to you.

Answer (score 1):

All of the answers given are sensible, but I'm not sure they're realistic.  Yes, Microsoft have been wanting to get rid of VBA for some time now, and I'm sure they dearly wish that Visual Studio Tools for Office would take off; and yes, VB.NET and C# both support something called classes (using object-orientated programming) much better than VBA does.

HOWEVER ... the world uses VBA!  Particularly for Excel solutions, I'd guess about 99% of all systems ever written use VBA.  So personally I'd learn VBA, helped by the fact that:

1. You can record macros to see how to do things; and
2. It's built into Excel (no need to buy or install any other software).

I've written a [VBA tutorial online](http://www.wiseowl.co.uk/blog/s161/online-excel-vba-training.htm) which I hope will help, full of example code and diagrams.  Let me know what you think of it, if you should use it.

PS It might seem that my advice is somewhwat biased, but it isn't.  We train on VSTO, C# and VB.NET, and my personal preferred programming environment by some way is Visual Studio (VBA drives me mad when I have to revert to it now).  However, that's the result of nearly 20 years of learning!  For a new programmer, VBA is much simpler to learn.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft plans to get rid of VBA sometime in the future. Support was already dropped from the Mac version of Office 2008 for example. It way stay around in the Windows version for some time, but no significant new development will be done on it.

Seeing you have C and Java knowledge, and considering you're starting fresh, I'd definitely go with .NET. It's simply the better investment for your time.

Like Jon Skeet says, C# (4.0) is probably your best option **if** you don't mind using beta software.

Comment: Not true. MS probably plans to get rid of many things in the future, the question is how far in the future. VBA is being reintroduced in the next Office for the Mac. VBA is an ancient technology, but it won't go away anytime soon. I don't know what the life cycle of a MS product is exactly, but I'd say 10 years. Heck, we still use Office XP at my company.

Comment: and we are still using Office 97! I haven't seen any real reason for upgrading more than 100  clients apart from a few.

Comment: Ouch, I pity you both :)

Comment: And VBA is being added back into the next version of Mac Office.   VBA is in the next version of Office currently being beta tested.   In my not so humble opinion "MS plans to get rid of VBA sometime in the future." is spreading FUD Fear, Uncertainty and Doubt.